# finding $\int {\tan^{3/2} 3x\sec 3x\,dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How do I integrate this expression?
$$\int \tan^{3/2} 3x\sec 3x dx$$

Comment: I've been chugging away at this problem using Mathematica Online to no avail... I'm starting to think this problem is going to be quite difficult to solve.

Comment: I thought the same Brevan

Comment: Can you tell what **you** tried? @shuuichi_nitori. And where did you get this?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal this one is a homework from my calculus class, I didn't get too far anyway.

Comment: It's funny, ever my teacher can't resolve it

Answer (score 2):

Notice, $$\int \tan^{3/2} 3x\sec 3x\ dx=\int \sqrt{\tan3x}.\tan3x.\sec3xdx$$

So if we let $\sec 3x=t$, $3\sec3x\tan3xdx=dt$, 

 We get,
$$\frac13\int\sqrt{\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt$$
**Wolfram:**
 [image]

 But as you can see, and deduce, there is not a closed form of it, so, I don't think there is an answer of your question in elementary functions. 
**Edit:** Lets try something. Put $t=\sin \theta;dt=\cos \theta d\theta$ 
Our integral becomes $$\int\sqrt{-\cos\theta} \cos \theta d\theta$$
$$=\int i\cos^{\frac32}\theta d\theta$$
Wolfram Says: [image] 
We can treat $i$ as a constant, but still there won't be an integral in terms of an elementary function. This tells that even if we switch from real plane to complex plane, integral will not exist in an elementary form.

Comment: Will this help? $$\sec3x=\frac{2}{e^{-3\iota x}+e^{3\iota x}}$$??

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Whichever way you attempt this question, I don't think we are going to get a solution in elementary form.

Comment: Ah, the solution seems much more correct now. I'm not sure if that will help... I've studied the hypergeometric functions a bit, and they easily cover complex domain. You can't always simplify the hypergeometric function to any elementary function... as unfortunate as this is, at least we have a closed form for the solution (albeit a hard to evaluate solution)

Comment: Is there any example where Wolfram gives the answer in non-elementary form but we **can** simplify it in an elementary form?

Comment: Seems like this conversation is going a bit above my level.... @BrevanEllefsen I think you should continue. xD

Comment: I also don't know these functions, but I saw this function on Wolfram and it was not an elementary function.  @Gummybears.

Comment: The hypergeometric function does have some identities, for example $(1-z)^{-a} =  _2F_1(a,1;1;z)$... I will check these on wolfram alpha and Mathematica

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen But they cannot be expressed in elementary terms, right?

Comment: Can it help? I don't think there will be an elementary form?

Comment: I doubt there will be a *elementary* form, but to answer your question yes, sometimes non-elementary functions can be simplified, so we can't be 100% certain its non-elementary without breaking out Galois theory I believe. I know a little Galois theory, but not a lot... I am only 16...

Comment: Hmm, so lets wait. No other option? @BrevanEllefsen.

Comment: It appears that even Wolfram Alpha will handle identities of the Hypergeometric function, which makes me much more sure this is non-elementary. Of course, we made a substitution in there, so perhaps back substituting will help... more likely though it will cause worse problems. Wouldn't hurt to try though.

Comment: Can we integrate taking $i$ to be constant?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but the number $i$ does count as a constant while integrating. If you are asking about a specific case I would need to see it written out.

Comment: $\int i\cos x dx$?

Comment: https://www.math.ust.hk/~maykwok/courses/ma304/06_07/Complex_4.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately, after the substitution I'm getting (sec(3 x) (2 tan^2(3 x)-(-tan^2(3 x))^(3/4) 2F1(1/2, 3/4, 3/2, sec^2(3 x))))/(3 tan^2(3 x)^(3/4)) which I'm not going to bother TeXing.

Comment: To simplify that link he sent, $\int i \cos(x) dx = i \sin(x)$. That link basically says ∫(a+bi) = ∫a + i∫b when $b$ and $a$ are real valued functions (in the case $i \cos(x)$, $\cos(x)$ is our $b$ and $a$ is 0)

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I found something useful guys. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunction.html. Apparently $\sqrt{1-x^4}$ is proven nonelementary... I feel like if I could find source or manipulate that I could show that the function is non-elementary

Comment: No, that link is for definite integrals!

Comment: But your integral of iota and cosine function is right.

Comment: There is one use of a definite integral on the page, but the one of interest is at the bottom, and is a plain antiderivative - see this image http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/ElementaryFunction/NumberedEquation1.gif

Comment: There is an elliptic function.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Unfortunately, that probably settles it. Except at special values where the polynomial involved has repeated roots (it doesn't here) or when there are no odd powers of the second argument, which I am having difficulty proving but is almost assured to be false, especially since the function can be simplified in this case and Wolfram Alpha likely would have done so. Well, we did our best guys. Thanks for all the help Aditya.

Comment: No problem. I learnt from you. Thank you! @BrevanEllefsen. And also GummyBears! (Cannot tag)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll let you know that no CAS system I have access to can solve this problem. The obvious first step is to change the equation from $\tan^{\frac{3}{2}}(3x)\sec(3x)$ to $3x\tan^{\frac{3}{2}}(x)\sec(3x)$, but that yields no more results. We do know that $$\int \tan^{3/2}(x)dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{4} (2 \sqrt{2} \,\tan^{-1}(1-\sqrt{2}\,\tan^{1/2}(x))-2 \sqrt{2} \,\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{2}\,\tan^{1/2}(x)+1)+ 8\tan^{1/2}(x)+\sqrt{2} \,\log(\tan(x)-\sqrt{2} \,\tan^{1/2}(x)+1)-\sqrt{2}\, \log(\tan(x)+\sqrt{2} \,\tan^{1/2}(x)+1))+constant$$
But I haven't been able to get anywhere with this monstrosity.

(I can't explain to you how much of my life was spent making that statement look pretty in MathJax.)

Answer (score 0):

With some changes of variables, it is easy to obtain an Incomplete Beta function as closed form :

[image]